# One event handler for multiple keyup events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to instantly display the user's input so each input has a corresponding display div.

The html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('contact_person'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('mobile'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for=""><?php echo __('Contact Person'); ?></label>
        <div id="test1"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for=""><?php echo __('Mobile'); ?></label>
        <div id="test2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$('#PostContactPerson').keyup(function(){
   $('#test1').html(this.value);
});
$('#PostMobile').keyup(function(){
   $('#test2').html(this.value);
});
```

I am new to JavaScript; is there a way to combine all these same scripts so one key function handles all instant input display?

Comment: You better use `class` instead of using IDs!

Comment: If you are new to javascript, I encourage you to know native javascript well before using jQuery.

Comment: I can find all input fields by class. I'm not sure how to output different user input to respective divs with classes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
  var outputId = null;
  switch ($(this).attr('name')) {
      case 'contact_person': outputId = '#test1'; break;
      case 'mobile': outputId = '#test2'; break;
  }
  $(outputId).html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input name='contact_person' type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input name='mobile' type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="">Contact Person</label>
        <div id="test1"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="">Mobile</label>
        <div id="test2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Consider this (I changed the HTML for the example to work, but your HTML is just fine)

But you may want to change the ID of your output fields:

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
  $('#output_'+$(this).attr('name')).html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input name='contact_person' type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input name='mobile' type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <label for="">Contact Person</label>
    <div id="output_contact_person"></div>
  </div>  
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <label for="">Mobile</label>
    <div id="output_mobile"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case the ID of the output field is the same as the name of your input field, but with a prepended "output_"

Or if you have some fields which shoudl not work with output field, consider telling the input-fields that they have an output field:

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
  var outputId = $(this).data('output');
  if (outputId) {
    $(outputId).html($(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input name='contact_person' type="text" data-output="#test1" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input name='mobile' type="text" data-output="#test2" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <label for="">Contact Person</label>
    <div id="test1"></div>
  </div>  
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <label for="">Mobile</label>
    <div id="test2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the data-output-attribute to link to output-div.

Comment: Sorry, I got carried away ;)

Comment: WOW Thank you so much! Elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the source of the event of the handler function two ways: `this` or `event.target`:

```
<div>first</div>
<div>second</div>

<script>
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i=0; i<divs.length; ++i) divs[i].addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});
</script>
```

Try clicking the divs [on the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vr88hgy/).

There are many methods for [DOM traversal](http://javascript.info/tutorial/traversing-dom), but if you want to use ids, you can create dictionary:

```
var targets = {
  "PostContactPerson": "test1",
  "PostMobile": "test2"
};
```

and the handler function would be

```
function(e) {
  $('#'+targets[this.id]).html(this.value);
}
```